# How to format a string that contains a big raw XML to a formated XML object or string/stream?

Tags: java, xml, formatting

How can i format a raw XML string to the original XML format?

The string that contains XML looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="http://webservice">       <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-28FC7B32CCC1BB2B21141113657641136"><wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">password=</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">gt/swtwet/ww==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2014-09-19T14:22:56.411Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>       <soapenv:Body>          <v2:getThis1>             <v2:getThis12>                <v3:getThis13>                   <v3:getThis10>                      <v31:Id>31045243</v31:Id>                      <v31:getThis1222>545345</v31:getThis1222>                   </v3:getThis10>                   <v3:Number>1234124</v3:Number>                </v3:getThis14323>             </v2:getThis1343>          </v2:getThis112>       </soapenv:Body>    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can i transform this back to XML format?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _pretty print ... to a hashmap_??

Comment: To make it in XML format again, because now it is a very long string.

Comment: I still don't understand how XML and an `HashMap` are in any way related. XML = complex structural data; `HashMap` = key -> value mapping. Please rephrase your question explaining clearly and concisely what you actually want to do.

Comment: well, to put line by line(<tag>text</tag>) in a map and compare the values.

Comment: And what about `<tag>text<tag>text</tag>text</tag>`?

Comment: good question, but i don't have that problem in my XMLs

Comment: In that case, please post an example of your XML and _exactly_ what issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: you could at least have formatted the XML. How are we supposed to give you advice on how to parse the XML if we cannot read it?

Comment: that is the idea, how can i format it in java? i need to arrange the response i get in a string(one line), to a nice XML formated string or stream.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that problem you want to solve is how to compare to XML objects based their string representation. If that's the case then just use [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/index.html#What%20is%20XMLUnit?) and that will compare the xml string and report the differences without having to worry about formatting, putting stuff in hashmaps etc.

Comment: thanks, i used XMLUnit but i need something else now

Comment: i need to arrange the response i get in a string(one line), to a nice XML formated string or stream.